# Update temp table with Min Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to update the `InsertDate` for all the distinct `AccId` and `AccNameHolder` combinations in the `#tmpResults` table only if an earlier insert date exists.

The table schemas are like so:

**#tmpResults**

```
Trans | AccId | AccountNameHolder | EarlyDate | CardType
```

**PositionCollection**

```
Id | AccId | InsertDate | BtchId
```

**CardErrors**

```
AccId | AccNameHolder | BtchId | TransId
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE  RES  
SET     EarlyDate = pc.InsertDate   
FROM  ( dbo.PositionCollection pc    
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CardErrors ce ON ce.BtchId = pc.BtchId AND pc.id =     ce.Transid  )    
    INNER JOIN #tmpResults RES   
ON      RES.AccId = pc.AccId    
AND     RES.AccNameHolder = ce.AccNameHolder    
WHERE   RES.EarlyDate = (SELECT MIN(InsertDate) FROM PostionCollection)    
AND     RES.AccId = pc.AccId    
AND     RES.AccNameHolder = ce.AccNameHolder
```

Comment: Can you describe your problem? You are just saying what you are doing. Do you get an error?

Comment: Hi - I do not get an error. The code is not updating the EarlyDate as expected. Here is the SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28a81/8/0    AccId 12345 is a good example of where the date should be updated

Answer (score 0):

Heres a few more general solutions, for where InsertDate is null, You can use them with DateDiff to change the conditions to earlier, later or whatever or just something like

```
OldInstDate <= COALESCE(NewInstDate, OldInstDate)
```

The conditional update can be achieved within the select statement so...

```
SET InsertDate = COALESCE(InsertDate, NewInsertDate) WHERE...
```

OR

```
SET InsertDate = CASE WHEN InsertDate IS NULL THEN NewInsertDate 
                      ELSE InsertDate END
```

OR

```
WHERE ...
AND InsertDate IS NULL
```

For really clear  help on sub queries
http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html
I think this is probably the best I've seen and http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html for trouble shooting

Answer (score 0):

Use derived table in your UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE x
SET x.EarlyDate = x.InsertDate  
FROM  ( 
       SELECT RES.EarlyDate, pc.InsertDate
       FROM dbo.PositionCollection pc
         LEFT JOIN dbo.CardErrors ce ON ce.BtchId = pc.BtchId AND pc.id = ce.Transid
         INNER JOIN #tmpResults RES ON RES.AccId = pc.AccId
           AND RES.AccNameHolder = ce.AccNameHolder
       WHERE RES.EarlyDate = (SELECT MIN(InsertDate) FROM PostionCollection) AND RES.AccId = pc.AccId
         AND RES.AccNameHolder = ce.AccNameHolder
       ) x
```

UPDATE 27.11.2012

```
UPDATE x
SET x.EarlyDate = x.InsertDate
FROM  (
       SELECT RES.EarlyDate, m.InsertDate
       FROM dbo.PositionCollection pc
         LEFT JOIN dbo.CardErrors ce ON ce.BtchId = pc.BtchId AND pc.id = ce.Transid
         INNER JOIN #tmpResults RES ON RES.AccId = pc.AccId AND RES.AccNameHolder = ce.AccNameHolder
         INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(InsertDate) AS InsertDate FROM PostionCollection) m
           ON RES.EarlyDate = m.InsertDate 
       ) x
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, however I'm getting incorrect syntax errors:     _Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'._

Comment: It is not returning the min date. It only returns the existing min date from the temp table but not the min date in the PositionCollection table. For readability, I have changed the InsertDate on the temptable to EarlyDate. I then change your query to `SET x.EarlyDate = x.InsertDate` but no luck still

Comment: Not quite there yet, I've put something into SQL Fiddle here to illustrate the problem: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28a81/8/0 AccId 12345 is a good example of where the date should be updated . I'm also trying to write it using windowing functions but I have not posted my attempts here yet. Really appreciated.

Comment: i.e. in POSITIONCOLLECTION table [InserDate] column with Id:6676, 6677, 6680 and 6681 should be updated on [EarlyDate]?

Comment: The dates in the PositionCollection table should be earlier than the dates in the tmpResults table (this is a typo on my part). I want the dates updated in tmpResults for each accid/accnameholder combination.

Comment: Sorry, but I reached a deadlock))

Comment: Hi see my edit on sub query examples that I added to my answer: